# customized xaxis labels with actions in coreplot graph

Tags: ios, graph, core-plot

In my app i have a graph where on xaxis i need to show some buttons with a background image and an action to every button. I am able to add labels with text as xaxis labels as follows.

```
    int labelLocations = 0;
    NSMutableArray *customXLabels = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSString *day in arrData) {

            CPTTextStyle *xaxisTextStyle = [CPTTextStyle textStyle];
            xaxisTextStyle.color = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:204.0/255.0 green:204.0/255.0 blue:204.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
            xaxisTextStyle.fontSize = 18.0;
            xaxisTextStyle.textAlignment = CPTTextAlignmentRight;

            CPTAxisLabel *newLabel = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:day textStyle:xaxisTextStyle];
            newLabel.tickLocation   = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:labelLocations] decimalValue];
            newLabel.offset         = axisSet.xAxis.labelOffset + axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLength;
            newLabel.alignment = CPTAlignmentLeft;

            [customXLabels addObject:newLabel];
            labelLocations++;

            UIImage*    backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_edit.png"];
        CALayer*    aLayer = [CALayer layer];
        CGFloat nativeWidth = CGImageGetWidth(backgroundImage.CGImage);
        CGFloat nativeHeight = CGImageGetHeight(backgroundImage.CGImage);
CGRect      startFrame = CGRectMake(newLabel.contentLayer.frame.origin.x+newLabel.contentLayer.frame.size.width,0, nativeWidth, nativeHeight);
        aLayer.contents = (id)backgroundImage.CGImage;
        aLayer.frame = startFrame;
        [newLabel.contentLayer addSublayer:aLayer];
        newLabel.contentLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;

        }
        axisSet.xAxis.axisLabels   = [NSSet setWithArray:customXLabels];
```

Can some help me to add button instead of CPTAxisLabel.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an axis delegate to detect touches on the axis labels. Implement the `-axis:labelWasSelected:` method or one of the other selection methods. The `contentLayer` of the axis label is a `CPTTextLayer` so you can add a background fill and border to make it look like a button.

If you'd rather use a real `UIButton`, add them as subviews of the parent view of your graph hosting view, not to the hosting view. Use the plot space to convert data coordinates to pixel coordinates to find button positions that line up with the graph.

Comment: Hi Eric thanks for the answer. I need to show an icon image beside every axis label. If we assume we still use labels as axis labels, can you suggest how can i show small icon images with same label action.

Comment: Depending on your requirements, you might be able to make the icon part of an image fill for the label. If not, try adding some padding to the text layer (the label's `contentLayer`) to leave room for the icon. Make the icon the fill for another `CPTBorderedLayer` and add that as a sublayer of the text layer. You might have to use a custom `CPTLayer` subclass and override `-layoutSublayer` to get the layout you want.

Comment: Hi Eric, I tried adding icon images to axis labels by creating a sublayer adding it to the axis label content layer. I edited my question to show you the code i used for that. But the problem is with the frame of the image layer. It is not starting at the end of the label text as expected. Can you tell what i am missing here.

Comment: The icon layer (`aLayer`) needs to be a `CPTLayer` or a subclass such as `CPTBorderedLayer`. Also, as I mentioned above, you might need to subclass `CPTTextLayer` for the label and override the sublayer layout to position the icon where you want it.